# Threading.Timer File Create issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety, imageresizer

I have a host which is medium trust level, im using imageresizer nuget package for my image processes. So when i'm trying to using ImageBuilder.Build i got this error:

```
    Access to the path '(path)' is denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '(path)' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension)
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource)
   at _10oy.UI.Web.Imager.Models.Downloader.SaveAndSetDimension(String path, Int32 width, Int32 height)
```

btw: (path)'s edited by me.

I research error but i didn't find any effective result.

here is my code (i'm calling it in threading.timer, it can be issue ?)

```
    public void SaveAndSetDimension(string path, int width, int height)
    {
        try
        {
            ImageBuilder.Current.Build(_MainStream, path, new ResizeSettings() { MaxWidth = width, MaxHeight = height }, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Results.Failed++;
            DAL.Classes.Log.Write(
            message: ex.Message,
            innerexcepition: ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.ToString() : ex.ToString(),
            user: "Saver",
            interfaces: 4 //Imager
            );
        }
    }
```

and i tried regular file create in action

```
    public ContentResult CreateFile()
    {
        System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/myfile.txt"));

        return Content("File Created");
    }
```

and its work.

thanks.

edit: When i call it on normal action its working great but when call in timer i got this error.

Comment: Can your manual CreateFile() method write to the *same* path that ImageResizer is trying to write to?

Comment: Yes, i try it. And its worked.

Comment: Hmm, tricky. It's possible that ImageResizer is handing off the work to a plug in which requires more privileges. Are you using any plugins?

Comment: i find it but i can't mark as answer for now ^^ read my answer :P thanks !

Comment: Ah, glad you solved it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it. Thread was using another windows identity because of that it can't create a file or delete or anything. I fix it like that;

Get identity from application_start etc. like this.

```
        identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
```

after that, call this before file process

```
        identity.Impersonate();
```

and it work.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you're calling this from a timer - is it possible you've got a previous run of the timer still around?  Try ensuring you use a unique file each time the timer is run to verify that your program is not locking the file against itself.

Comment: you can be sure, always different file creating. so its unique

Comment: and its working on my pc (full trust), when trying to work on host i get this error. I give all permission from host site (write-read) to all files. Also i give ftp permission from filezilla